# how to apply multiple filters to table using strongloop

Tags: strongloop

please help me in applying mulpiple filters in strong loop

http://localhost:3000/api/isoCounts/count?where[flage]=true

to this i need to add one more where condition [flage2]=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://localhost:3000/api/isoCounts/count?[where][and][0][flage]=true&[where][and][1][flage2]=false
```

should work according to the documentation at https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Where+filter